# iOS CGPDFScanner to search locate text positions

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, pdf

I am building an iPhone/iPad application to read pdf files and so far managed to download, open file, zoom in/out, bookmark etc. Since I am not an expert programmer, I was only able to do this after reading lots of blogs and questions on stackoverflow.

I have also included a search function and found the following site helpful in explaining the use of CGPDFScanner 
http://www.random-ideas.net/posts/42

Now the mystery to solve is locating the text position in the pdf and highlight the results (exactly like in iBooks). Many people have already said pdf parsing is very complicated and I am hoping someone can share their code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After two weeks of painful search I finally found this!

[FastPdfKit](http://fastpdfkit.com)

Comment: have your application been approved by apple by using this.As the same i need to do in my application.I downloaded this code and using it's really good.So please let me know bro....

Comment: @sabby, no i haven't submitted my app yet. Right now I am getting familiar with the kit, but so far so good. The guys at Mobfarm have been responsive to answer my questions. I look forward to their code updates.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.....I will see further as i am also in middle of my work.Thanks again

Comment: @topace have you found there a method to extract text position?

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander no I gave up long time ago.